# Manipulating 3D images in python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

Is there a way in SciPy to import 3D images of .nrrd format and rotate the image to a specific view(to some given specific coordinates) and then display the image?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should be more specific on your question. Which research did you do so far? What have you tried to fix the issue? You should update your question with that.

Comment: Have you already tried with pynrrd.read ?